# How to avoid text over lapping with fixed top offset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add comments on a text editor where the comments appear aside the text commented. For that i used this function:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('span.comment').each(function () {
        var id=jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
        var top=jQuery(this).offset().top - 40;
        jQuery(document).find('article[id="'+id+'"]').each(function () {
            jQuery(this).css('top',top);
        });
    });
});
```

In this function i detect the position of the text commented and add the comment at the same y position.

But when two commented texts are close to each other the comments overlap and their text is not readable anymore is there a way to avoid that or another idea to do it??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Make your comments container scrollable (overflow-y:auto;) and set its max-height same as commented text height.